# DRDA .net native driver

Tags: .net, driver, native

I'm writing ADO.NET data provider for DB2. I need a DRDA protocol driver, implemented natively in C#, but I was unable to find anything. I have DRDA protocol specification, but I want to avoid writing it myself. Implementations in other languagges are also considerable.